# Running migration file before ./manage.py migrate component

Tags: django

I have update our project from svn. There was a migration file in update. I have run this migration file before `./manage.py migrate component` . Now I have this error:

```
raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % 
ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

How can I solve this? I have deleted the migration file and updated again but nothing fixed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: migration file is an auto add filed

Comment: What? That doesn't help at all (or indeed make any sense). You need to provide some actual useful information if you want someone to help you.

Comment: I have deleted the line related to migration in south history and problem solved. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

You do not have a system Environment Variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, see the site above on how to set the environment variable.

Comment: before update everything was ok. But when I run the migration file I have many errors like File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/South-0.7.3-py2.6.egg/south/db/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    engine = getattr(settings, "SOUTH_DATABASE_ADAPTER", "south.db.%s" % settings.DATABASE_ENGINE)